# Не получается сравнить даты, если больше или меньше текущего времени Calendar.MONTH

Tags: java, android

Я пытаюсь проверять дату, чтобы поставить подходящий сепаратор, но проблема в том, что сравнение `Calendar.MONTH` не происходит, а остальные проверки нормально работают.

Подскажите, как можно это сделать ?

```
if   (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) > Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) && calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) > Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) ||
                        (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) && calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) > Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)) ||
                        (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) && calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) > Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR))||
                        (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) && calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) > Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)&&calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) == Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)))
                        {
                newTask.setDateStatus(ModelSeparator.TYPE_FUTURE);
                if (!adapter.containsSeparatorFuture) {
                    adapter.containsSeparatorFuture = true;
                    separator = new ModelSeparator(ModelSeparator.TYPE_FUTURE);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Future",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comment: Что проверяет это условие? Если вам просто надо проверить, что дата в `calendar` больше текущей, то `Calendar` реализует `Comparable`, и достаточно вызвать `compareTo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Класс Calendar реализует методы after(Object calendar) и before(Object calendar), с помощью которых легко сравнивать даты.